# How to count total users in a BeforeSave CloudCode on Parse Platform

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    var query = new new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.count({
      success: function(count) {
        request.object.set("membersNumber", count+1);
        response.success();     
      },
      error: function(error) {
        response.success(); 
      }
    });
});
```

On a Parse backend, I want to assign a sequential number to every user who registered. For example, first member will get a membersNumber = 1, second member will get a membersNumber = 2, etc.

But the code above fails. Count is always zero. I suspect the beforeSave function does not have the master credentials to get all user objects?

How can count the total users in this beforeSave method?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. Need to pass useMasterKey:true in the count method.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    if(request.user == undefined){
        //new sign up
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.count({
            useMasterKey:true,
            success: function(count) {
                var membersNumber = count+1;
                request.object.set("membersNumber", membersNumber);
                response.success();     
            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.success(); 
            }
        });
    }else{
        response.success();
    }
});
```